# kendo ui chart - add html and multiple values to series.Labels.Template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

For this example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/arIhI/2

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { score: 1.1, legend: 'a' },
      { score: 2.5, legend: 'b' },
      { score: 3.25, legend: 'c' }
    ]
  },
  series: [{
    field: "score",   
    labels: {
      visible: true,
      template: "Score is: #: value #% legend is: ????"
    },
  }]
});
```

2 questions:

1) is it possibly to add html to the template ( say **Value is:** ....)?

2) is it possible to add multiple values to the label. I'd like to add score and the legend.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Sure

```
template: "<b>Score is:</b> #: value #% legend is: ????"
```

is valid template.

2) Do it like this:

```
template: "Score is: #= dataItem.score #% legend is: #= dataItem.legend #"
```

or by using a function which I think is more convenient:

```
template: function(e) { return "Score is: " + e.dataItem.score + "% legend is: " + e.dataItem.legend }
```

**UPDATE**:
  It currently is not possible to add html to series.labels.templates.

Comment: 1) adding html to the template isn't working.  it causes the labels to fall below the chart.   2) works great. thanks!

Comment: I believe that i misunderstood what is your problem in 1). Check this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/icOC When you hover over chart you'll see bold country name and normal value.

Comment: I opened a ticket with telerik and html currently is not supported for series.labels.templates.  lame!.. I updated your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: dataItem is not defined

Comment: @Jedaias Rodrigues here is example with latest kendo: http://dojo.telerik.com/arIhI/58 same solution works for me. You just can't use bold text as RayLoveless said.